# Smooth affine varieties are normal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

My original goal was to show for affine curves over $\mathbb{C}$, being normal is the same as smooth. For this, there are two pieces of lemma: smooth->normal, and normal implies singular points has codim >=2. I could prove the latter one with elementary tools.

The definition I am working over with are

Smooth at a point if the local ring is a regular local ring (i.e. dim m/m^2=dim A).

Normal if every localization at maximal ideal is integrally closed.

I don't see how dimensions are connected to being integrally closed.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$, smooth is regular, and regular rings are normal. If I recall correctly this is not an easy fact, one way to see it is from Serre's Criterion for Normality.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$, smooth and regular are equivalent. But this is not true over every base.

Comment: I'm guessing you can't use that a regular local ring is a UFD.

Comment: For curves, nonsingular $\implies$ normal is basically Prop. 9.2 in Atiyah-Macdonald.

Comment: @DKS I am aware of normality <-> R1+S2. R1 is precisely being smooth, and I don't know how to interpret (or prove) S2 in this setting.

Comment: @André 3000 Is the result not true in general?

Comment: @MattKeller I'm not sure what you mean by in general, but I just meant that there are higher dimensional normal varieties that are singular. (Just with singular locus in codimension $\geq 2$, as you mention.) For instance, the cone $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ in $\mathbb{A}^3$.